# Using dbf.Table: how to create index with two or more fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbf

Can I create one or more fields to index on in the dbf module..

```
empInfo_table = dbf.Table('C:\Sonichr\\empInfo.DBF')
empInfo_table.open()
empInfo_index = empInfo_table.create_index(key = lambda rec: rec.storeid, rec.ssn - I get a syntax error)
print(empInfo_index)
for empInfo_rec in empInfo_table:      
    ssn = empInfo_rec.ssn
    storeid = empInfo_rec.storeid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is one of Python syntax.

```
lambda arg1, arg2: some_expression, # lambda ends at first comma after the colon
```

To protect the comma and make it part of what `lambda` returns, you parentheses:

```
lambda rec: (rec.storeid, rec.ssn)
```

Comment: ETHAN youre a life saver!

Comment: @BillJudge:  You're welcome.  :)  Please up-vote and accept the answer when you get a chance.